# Unable to change int value set in one activity from another

Tags: java, android

I'm trying to set a counter to 0 by clicking on a `ImageButton` in my alert activity, the counter is in Server.java class (that's a **TCP server**) but when I'm trying to change the value by setting in my **alert.java** :

```
Server server;
    refreshing.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            server.count = 0;
            SharedPreferences prefs = getSharedPreferences("MY_DATA", MODE_PRIVATE);
            SharedPreferences.Editor editor = prefs.edit();
            editor.clear();
            editor.apply();
            Intent intent = getIntent();
            overridePendingTransition(0, 0);
            intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_ANIMATION);
            finish();
            overridePendingTransition(0, 0);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });
```

that crashes with error :

`Java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to write to field 'int com.example.sguidetti.selfmanegment.Server.count' on a null object reference`

While I'm using the same action in main activity for resetting the same counter by clicking another `ImageButton` and that works.

(Ps: I'm new in android so I couldn't understand a lot of stuff)

**EDIT** here is Server.java

```
public class Server {
DataBaseHandler myDB;
allert Allert;
MainActivity activity;
RecyclerViewAdapter adapterView;
Adapter adapter;
ServerSocket serverSocket;
public static int count=0;
String letto = "";
private SharedPreferences prefs;
static final int socketServerPORT = 8080;

public Server(MainActivity activity) {
    this.activity = activity;
    Thread socketServerThread = new Thread(new SocketServerThread());
    socketServerThread.start();
}

public int getPort() {
    return socketServerPORT;
}


public void onDestroy() {
    if (serverSocket != null) try {
        serverSocket.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}


private class SocketServerThread extends Thread {
    Vibrator vibrator;
    String date,ora;
    long[] pattern = {0, 1000, 500, 1000, 500, 1000};

    int lun;

    @Override
    public void run() {
        InputStream leggi;
        try {


            serverSocket = new ServerSocket(socketServerPORT);

            while (true) {
                myDB = DataBaseHandler.getInstance(activity);

                Socket socket = serverSocket.accept();
                leggi = socket.getInputStream();
                byte[] data = new byte[1000];
                lun = leggi.read(data, 0, data.length);
                letto = new String(data, "UTF-8");
                count++;
                MediaPlayer mPlay = MediaPlayer.create(activity, R.raw.gabsuono);
                mPlay.start();

                vibrator = (Vibrator) activity.getSystemService(VIBRATOR_SERVICE);
                vibrator.vibrate(pattern, -1);

                date = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy").format(new Date());
                ora = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ss").format(new Date());
                myDB.insertDataServer(date, ora, letto);


                //adapterView.notifyDataSetChanged();

                activity.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        prefs = activity.getSharedPreferences("MY_DATA", MODE_PRIVATE);
                        SharedPreferences.Editor edit = prefs.edit();
                        edit.putInt("counter", count);
                        edit.commit();
                        activity.msg.setText(String.valueOf(count));
                        activity.msg.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

                    }
                });
                leggi.close();


            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();

        }

    }


}

public void Parti() {
    prefs = activity.getSharedPreferences("MY_DATA", MODE_PRIVATE);
    count = prefs.getInt("counter", count);
    activity.msg.setText("" + count);
    if (count == 0)
        activity.msg.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
    else
        activity.msg.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);


}

}
```

Comment: Can you post Server class ?

Comment: @Frank edited, now you can look at the code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to make that int static

```
public static final int count = 0;
```

then you can access that value from another activity like this

```
Server.count = 5;
```

**UPDATE**

declare your count in server like this

```
public static final String COUNT = "count";
```

also declare

```
public static final String PREFS = "prefs";
```

And declare your shared prefes like this

```
 SharedPreferences prefs = getSharedPreferences(Server.PREFS, MODE_PRIVATE);
 SharedPreferences.Editor editor = prefs.edit();
```

then in your button click after you have called your sharedPreference

```
editor.putInt(Server.COUNT,5).commit();
```

then get the int value in your alert activity like this

```
int count = prefs.getInt(Server.COUNT,0);
```

Comment: Now the app doesn't crash but still when i return to the main activity the counter is still the same...

Comment: You can save the values to the shared preference instead of doing it like this.

Comment: yea i'm yet saving it in SharedPreference just look at the updated code, and i'm trying to reset it by :               SharedPreferences prefs = getSharedPreferences("MY_DATA", MODE_PRIVATE);
                SharedPreferences.Editor editor = prefs.edit();
                editor.clear();
                editor.apply();

Comment: Oh just fixed it, i just forgot to reset TextView to null after setting counter to 0 and to hide it, thank you for the public static tip that was very helpful.

Answer (score 0):

you forgot to initialize your `server` object, add :

```
Server server = new Server();
```

Comment: Server is initialized in MainActivity

Comment: can add the class where you call your dialog